# How to properly set a shared golang interface for hashicorp go-plugin to expose a method that accepts json string input

Tags: go, rpc

I am trying to develop a golang hashicorp go-plugin based on official published [example](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin/tree/main/examples/basic).
While the example exposes a method Greet() that does not take any argument, I am trying to expose a method CdExec(string) that accepts one argument of JSON string.
The response should also respond with a JSON string with two fields 'data' and 'status'.
Unexpected behaviour: Not getting response from the plugin but no error showing.
There are 3 main source codes involved.

1. A shared interface which is imported as: shared "github.com/tcp-x/cd-plug-util". Which is published from a seperate project
2. A source code for plugin
3. Main file for loading the plugin
   For 2 and 3, the source is available at https://github.com/tcp-x/hashicorp-plugin-02.

**Shared Interface source file:**

```
    // package shared contains the shared interface definition
package iExec

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/rpc"

    "github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin"
)

// CdExecutor represents the interface for executing commands in a plugin.
type CdExecutor interface {
    // CdExec is a method that executes a command and returns the result.
    CdExec(jsonInput string) (string, error)
}

// Here is an implementation that talks over RPC
type CdExecutorRPCClient struct {
    client *rpc.Client
}

func (g *CdExecutorRPCClient) CdExec(req string) (string, error) {
    var resp string
    err := g.client.Call("Plugin.CdExec", new(interface{}), &resp)
    if err != nil {
        // You usually want your interfaces to return errors. If they don't,
        // there isn't much other choice here.
        panic(err)
    }

    return resp, err
}

// Here is the RPC server that CdExecutorRPC talks to, conforming to
// the requirements of net/rpc
type CdExecutorRPCServer struct {
    // This is the real implementation
    Impl CdExecutor
}


func (s *CdExecutorRPCServer) CdExec(args interface{}, resp *string) error {
    fmt.Println("CdExecutorRPCServer::args:", args)
    // req := args.(string)
    *resp, _ = s.Impl.CdExec(fmt.Sprintf("%v", args))
    return nil
}

// This is the implementation of plugin.Plugin so we can serve/consume this
//
// This has two methods: Server must return an RPC server for this plugin
// type. We construct a CdExecutorRPCServer for this.
//
// Client must return an implementation of our interface that communicates
// over an RPC client. We return CdExecutorRPC for this.
//
// Ignore MuxBroker. That is used to create more multiplexed streams on our
// plugin connection and is a more advanced use case.
type CdExecutorPlugin struct {
    // Impl Injection
    Impl CdExecutor
}

func (p *CdExecutorPlugin) Server(*plugin.MuxBroker) (interface{}, error) {
    return &CdExecutorRPCServer{Impl: p.Impl}, nil
}

func (CdExecutorPlugin) Client(b *plugin.MuxBroker, c *rpc.Client) (interface{}, error) {
    return &CdExecutorRPCClient{client: c}, nil
}
```

**Plugin Source file:**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "os"

    "github.com/hashicorp/go-hclog"
    "github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin"
    shared "github.com/tcp-x/cd-plug-util" // Import the shared package
)

type CdExecutorPlugin struct {
    logger hclog.Logger
}

// CdExec is the method that executes a command and returns the result.
func (exec *CdExecutorPlugin) CdExec(jsonInput string) (string, error) {
    exec.logger.Debug("message from CdExecutorPlugin.CdExec")
    // Parse the JSON input
    var input map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonInput), &input)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Your logic here to execute the command based on the input
    // For demonstration, let's just return a JSON response
    response := map[string]interface{}{
        "data":   "Your result data",
        "status": "success",
    }
    responseJSON, err := json.Marshal(response)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(responseJSON), nil
}

var handshakeConfig = plugin.HandshakeConfig{
    ProtocolVersion:  1,
    MagicCookieKey:   "BASIC_PLUGIN",
    MagicCookieValue: "hello",
}

func main() {
    logger := hclog.New(&hclog.LoggerOptions{
        Level:      hclog.Trace,
        Output:     os.Stderr,
        JSONFormat: true,
    })

    exec := &CdExecutorPlugin{
        logger: logger,
    }

    // pluginMap is the map of plugins we can dispense.
    var pluginMap = map[string]plugin.Plugin{
        "cd_executor": &shared.CdExecutorPlugin{Impl: exec},
    }

    logger.Debug("message from plugin", "foo", "bar")
    // Serve the plugin using the CdExecutorPlugin
    plugin.Serve(&plugin.ServeConfig{
        HandshakeConfig: handshakeConfig,
        Plugins:         pluginMap,
    })
}
```

**Main file to load the plugin:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    hclog "github.com/hashicorp/go-hclog"
    "github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin"
    shared "github.com/tcp-x/cd-plug-util" // Import the shared package
)

// handshakeConfigs are used to just do a basic handshake between
// a plugin and host. If the handshake fails, a user friendly error is shown.
// This prevents users from executing bad plugins or executing a plugin
// directory. It is a UX feature, not a security feature.
var handshakeConfig = plugin.HandshakeConfig{
    ProtocolVersion:  1,
    MagicCookieKey:   "BASIC_PLUGIN",
    MagicCookieValue: "hello",
}

// pluginMap is the map of plugins we can dispense.
var pluginMap = map[string]plugin.Plugin{
    "cd_executor": &shared.CdExecutorPlugin{},
}

func main() {
    // Create an hclog.Logger
    logger := hclog.New(&hclog.LoggerOptions{
        Name:   "plugin",
        Output: os.Stdout,
        Level:  hclog.Debug,
    })

    // Create a plugin client
    client := plugin.NewClient(&plugin.ClientConfig{
        HandshakeConfig: handshakeConfig,
        Plugins:         pluginMap,
        Cmd:             exec.Command("./plugin/executor"),
        Logger:          logger,
    })

    // Connect via RPC
    rpcClient, err := client.Client()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error connecting:", err)
    }
    // defer rpcClient.Close()
    defer client.Kill()

    // Request the plugin
    raw, err := rpcClient.Dispense("cd_executor")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error getting plugin:", err)
    }
    executor := raw.(shared.CdExecutor)

    // Example input JSON string
    input := `{"key": "value"}`

    // Call the CdExec method of the plugin
    result, err := executor.CdExec(input)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error calling CdExec:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Plugin Result:", result)
}
```

**Compilation script**

```
go build -o ./plugin/executor ./plugin/plugin.go
go build -o CdPluginHost .
```

**Executing:**

```
./CdPluginHost
```

**Project directory**

```
├── bug-report-01
├── build.sh
├── CdPluginHost
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── main.go
└── plugin
    ├── executor
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    └── plugin.go
```

**Current output:**

```
2024-03-09T02:48:17.376+0300 [DEBUG] plugin: starting plugin: path=./plugin/executor args=[./plugin/executor]
2024-03-09T02:48:17.377+0300 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin started: path=./plugin/executor pid=158963
2024-03-09T02:48:17.377+0300 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for RPC address: plugin=./plugin/executor
2024-03-09T02:48:17.382+0300 [DEBUG] plugin.executor: message from plugin: foo=bar timestamp=2024-03-09T02:48:17.382+0300
2024-03-09T02:48:17.382+0300 [DEBUG] plugin.executor: plugin address: address=/tmp/plugin557806602 network=unix timestamp=2024-03-09T02:48:17.382+0300
2024-03-09T02:48:17.382+0300 [DEBUG] plugin: using plugin: version=1
2024-03-09T02:48:17.385+0300 [DEBUG] plugin.executor: message from CdExecutorPlugin.CdExec: timestamp=2024-03-09T02:48:17.385+0300
Plugin Result: 
2024-03-09T02:48:17.386+0300 [DEBUG] plugin.executor: 2024/03/09 02:48:17 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin server: accept unix /tmp/plugin557806602: use of closed network connection
2024-03-09T02:48:17.387+0300 [INFO]  plugin: plugin process exited: plugin=./plugin/executor id=158963
2024-03-09T02:48:17.387+0300 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
```

Comment: Your function receiver `func (g *CdExecutorRPCClient) CdExec(req string) string` does not match the interface's version: `CdExec(jsonInput string) (string, error)`. The argument names don't matter, but the input and output types do.

Comment: Thank you very much @coxley. I have made the correction now everything works without any error. But now there is no response. So the question as framed in the title still stand...but will modify with your guided correction.